# Nosql database structure with Realm

Tags: sqlite, nosql, realm, data-modeling

I've a SQLite database to migrate to a Realm database.

It has, among others, an `assoc` table, a `plant` table and a `definition` table :

[image]

The assoc table associates two plants. The definition table cointains the name of the plant in different languages.

Since I use a Realm database mapped to my POJO objects I have a class mapped to my assoc table (the Realm equivalent). This assoc class contains two Lists for plant_id1 and plant_id2. The problem is that I must be able to retrieve all the assoc with all the plant but I must be able to 
find all distinct plants too without needing the assoc.... I guess there is something i didn't understand with data modeling using nosql... but how can I do this ? do I have to replicate my plants data in the assoc and an in a list of plants outside of assoc ? i'm not sure to be totally clear here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess there is something i didn't understand with data modeling using nosql... but how can I do this ?

```
public class Plant extends RealmObject {
    // PK
    RealmList<Plant> associatedPlants;

    @LinkingObjects("plant1")
    private final RealmResults<Assoc> assoc1 = null;

    @LinkingObjects("plant2")
    private final RealmResults<Assoc> assoc2 = null;

    @LinkingObjects("associatedPlants")
    private final RealmResults<Plant> associatedByPlants = null;
}

public class Assoc extends RealmObject {
    // PK
    Plant plant1;
    Plant plant2;
}
```

Your definition seems to be wrong, if you want multiple definitions to belong to the plant, then you can't have the `definitionId` in the plant. I'd most likely just have a field for each language name anyways.